# Visual Basic.Net: Data Grid View Disable scroll Bar but allow Mouse wheel Scroll

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

As the title implies, I have two data grid view side by side with each other. I would like to have the first data grid view to have no scroll bar but allow mouse wheel scroll. I have already managed to synchronize the 2 data grid view when I scroll the second data grid view. below is the code

```
Private Sub dgvA_Scroll(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs) Handles dgvA.Scroll
    dgvB.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgvA.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex
    dgvB.HorizontalScrollingOffset = dgvA.HorizontalScrollingOffset
End Sub

Private Sub dgvB_Scroll(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs) Handles dgvB.Scroll
    dgvA.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgvB.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex
    dgvA.HorizontalScrollingOffset = dgvB.HorizontalScrollingOffset
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to do so using these codes

```
Private Sub dgvA_MouseWheel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles dgvA.MouseWheel
    Dim currentIndex As Integer = Me.dgvA.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex
    Dim scrollLines As Integer = SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines

    Select Case e.Delta
        Case (120)
            Me.dgvA.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = Math.Max(0, currentIndex - scrollLines)
        Case (-120)
            Me.dgvA.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = currentIndex + scrollLines
    End Select
End Sub
```